# echo-cancel does not work after PulseAudio rebuild

Tags: pulseaudio, compiling, deb, packaging

I work with Ubuntu 14.04.5 and faced troubles with rebuilding PulseAudio from source. PulseAudio here is 4.0-0ubuntu11.1, but I need to rebuild it and include recent patch https://patchwork.freedesktop.org/patch/65100/ which improves `echo-cancel` module.

I tried to rebuild PA following instructions from Ubuntu community docs https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpdatingADeb . I.e. `apt-get build-dep ...`, `apt-get source ...`, `patch ...`, `debchange -i`, `dpkg-source --commit`, `debuild -us -uc -i -I`. Built was successful, only one error - "pulseaudio: postrm-does-not-call-updaterc.d-for-init.d-script etc/init.d/pulseaudio", but I think it should be ignored. Then I installed built packages using `debi`, tried to launch PA and get following error:

```
$ pulseaudio -vvv
<...>
D: [pulseaudio] module-systemd-login.c: Added new session c2
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-systemd-login" (index: #14; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-position-event-sounds" (index: #15; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-filter-heuristics" (index: #16; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-filter-apply" (index: #17; argument: "").
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-open.c: 689: _dl_open: Assertion `_dl_debug_initialize (0, args.nsid)->r_state == RT_CONSISTENT' failed!
```

The moment when launch fails is exact the moment when `echo-cancel` module should start. Furthermore, even if I rebuild PA without any significant changes - I get same error. If I use PA from officical Ubuntu repo - it starts without any error and launchs `echo-cancel` module successfully.

This is how I enable `echo-cancel`, these lines I added to the end of `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
load-module module-echo-cancel source_name=noechosource sink_name=noechosink
set-default-source noechosource
set-default-sink noechosink
```

Could anybody suggest how can I solve this problem with rebuilding PA? Maybe the way I rebuild package is wrong in some point. As I said, the problem is not even with rebuilding modified PA, but with simple rebuilding it without any changes, so seems that the problem is with build process itself.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, at least in the main:

It is a specific deb building problem, not related to PulseAudio itself:

- The `RT_CONSISTENT` assertion failure was caused by the missing dependency of `module-echo-cancel.so`:
  `ldd` on this module shows `libwebrtc-util.so => not found` and according to `debuild` log this file was built, *but not packaged to deb* and so was not installed to the system
- The default `trusty` PA package is built *without support of WebRTC AEC* (and that's why you don't need and don't install `libwebrtc-util.so`).
- But I need exactly this kind of AEC and that's why I've installed the `libwebrtc-audio-processing-dev` package before rebuilding the PA. These WebRTC libs were caught by the PA configure script and the PA was built with WebRTC support, but during post-built steps not all required files were packaged to deb.
- Now as a temporary measure I manually moved `libwebrtc-util.so` to its desired location. Later I'll find out how to fix building scripts to handle this case correctly and come back and update this answer.